# Blockquote Markdown Syntax

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, markdown

I want to add blockquotes to my parser, like Stack Overflow, where `>` are used to mark a part of a blockquote.

Here is what I am doing to initiate the class:

```
<?php

$string = "This is a paragraph

> This is a blockquote
> This is a blockquote
> This is a blockquote

This is another paragraph
";
$md = new Markdown();
echo $md->parseString($string);
```

Here is what I am doing within the class to parse the blockquotes, the problem is, that it isn't finding the part I want to be quoted.

```
<?php
$this->string = preg_replace("/^>(.+?)/is", "<blockquote>$1</blockquote>", $this->string);
```

What can I do to find these multiline blockquotes?

Comment: do you want one blockquote tag for each line, or one blockquote tag for all the consecutive lines?

Comment: one blockquote tag for all the consecutive lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a replace with callback using `/(?:^>.+\n)+/m` then in the callback do a return of the result of replace $match[0] using this `/^>/m` , ""

```
 return '<blockquote>' + preg_replace( '/^>/m', "", $match[0] ) + '</blockquote>';
```

(I'm new to php)

Comment: That isn't working... Doing: `preg_match_all("/(?:^>[^\S\n]+\n)+/m", $this->string, $matches);
        
        print_r($matches); ` gives me an empty array.

Comment: Use `'/(?:^>.+\n)+/m'` (you caught me between edits).

Comment: Or you could use `'/(?:^>[^\n]+\n)+/m'`

Comment: One array element should be an entire block quote.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$subject = <<<'LOD'
This is a paragraph

> This is a blockquote
> This is a blockquote
> This is a blockquote

This is another paragraph
LOD;

$pattern = '~(?<=(\n)|)\R> (.*)(?=(\R> )?)~';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($match) {
    $before = (empty($match[1])) ? '' : '<blockquote>';
    $after  = (empty($match[3])) ? '</blockquote>' : '';
    return  $before . $match[2] . $after; }, $subject);

print_r($result);
```